# How to sort a listview by string numbers?

Tags: android, sorting, listview

Here is my main issue, after some researches, I didn't find a solution so... I would like to sort my list of custom objects. These items have a price, but for a reason they are strings not int. I would like to know how to achieve this, thanks for helping !

Little personnal question, sorting a listview and a recyclerview are they done the same way ?

EDIT:

```
public class Product implements Parcelable {
    private String imgUrl, titre, description, prix, nomAgence, pays, ville, type_produit, nbPieces = null;
    List<String> urlImageList_thumb = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> urlImageList_full = new ArrayList<>();
    private int isAdded = 0;

/* getters and setters*/
}
```

EDIT 2 :After your help, here's my code for comparable

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Product otherProduct) {
    String tmp = prix.replace(" €", "");
    String tmp2 = otherProduct.prix.replace(" €", "");

    //Integer p1 = Integer.valueOf(tmp);  --> does not work
    //Integer p2 = Integer.valueOf(tmp2); --> does not work

    Integer p1 = Integer.parseInt(tmp); //same error
    Integer p2 = Integer.parseInt(tmp2); // same error

    return p1.compareTo(p2);
}
```

Here's the code in the activity:

```
 bouton_tri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Collections.sort(productList);
        }
    });
```

EDIT 3 :

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Product otherProduct) {
    String tmp = prix.replace(" €", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
    String tmp2 = otherProduct.prix.replace(" €", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
    Integer p1 = Integer.valueOf(tmp);
    Integer p2 = Integer.valueOf(tmp2);
    return p1.compareTo(p2);
}
```

I still have an error, but when I just take off " €" the value is "5 300 000", if only spaces "5300000€". But putting both together gives me this error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "-" ... Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Collections.sort?

Comment: Share the sample data.

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad is write.

Comment: @P.Rai added code :)

Comment: Which list you want to sort? Please see my answer

Comment: Implement Comparable to your Product class and Override "compareTo" method with the code examples provided in below answers

Comment: you may wanna check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36349722/2032561

Comment: Your code is parser class and @P.Rai have added code bellow

Comment: I'm testing @Guillaume's answer, with comparable implementation

Comment: @P.Rai I want to sort my list of products in my mainActivity, the code I gave is only my Product class

Comment: You can call `Collections.sort(l);` wherever you have a reference on your list `l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make modify your `Product` class to implement Comparable

Before converting the `String` to an `Integer` you need to remove the `€`and all spaces.

```
public class Product implements Parcelable, Comparable<Product> {
    private String prix;

    //...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product otherProduct) {
        String tmp = prix.replace(" €", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
        String tmp2 = otherProduct.prix.replace(" €", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
        Integer p1 = Integer.valueOf(tmp);
        Integer p2 = Integer.valueOf(tmp2);
        return p1.compareTo(p2);
    }
}
```

Once done to sort your collection you can use : `Collections.sort(...);` this method will take as parameter the list of custom objects you are using in your adapter.

For example:

```
List<Product> l = new ArrayList();
Collections.sort(l);
```

> Note that sorting the collection will not refresh the views of the `recyclerview`.

You will have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to refresh the recyclerview:

You can do this in your main activity where you have declared your adapter :

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that it works, only problem I have is that I didn't notice the currency symbol in the string, so I have an error of invalid int, which is normal... I think it works so I will accept your answer

Comment: I would like to ask how to unsort the list ? I would like to use a button to sort/unsort the list, thanks @Guillaume !

Comment: have a look to `Collections.shuffle(...)` it's want you need...http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29

Comment: I found a way to take off the currency symbol but I have this error : java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "5 300 000"

Comment: String tmp = prix.replaceAll(" ", "");  
        String tmp2 = otherProduct.prix.replaceAll(" ", "");

        tmp = tmp.replace("€", "");
        tmp2 = tmp.replace("€", "");     I added this but it doesn't work, java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "-" otherwise to take off spaces it works

Comment: I don't know the exact format of the `prix` attribute but basically you must remove all characters other than "0123456789" before the convertion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me sorry bothering, but same error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "-". At first, the price format is for example "5 300 000 €", I followed your logic, you wrote the same code as me but still this error really annoying....

Comment: I found the problem, some of my values in the xml are "-", I just had to catch these cases, otherwise your code is perferct thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Just assuming you have  `List<String> sampleData` object

```
Collections.sort(sampleData, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String c1, String c2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(c1) -  Integer.valueOf(c2);
        }
    });
```

This will sort your data.

Answer (score 1):

```
(int) Integer.parseInt(p2.getNumberOfRecords()) - Integer.parseInt(p1.getNumberOfRecords())
```

So the simple compare of an integer in a String data type would not result correctly but to parse the string first by:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(string)
```

Comment: I used your solution mixed up with @Guillaume 's answer but does not work either, still have java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "5 300 000"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Collections.sort (list, new Comparator<String> () {

    @Override
    public int compare (String s1, String s2) {

        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});

OR


Collections.sort (list, new Comparator<String> () {

    @Override
    public int compare (String s1, String s2) {

        //cast string price to integer
        int price1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int price2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        if (price1 > price1) {

            return 1;
        }
        else if (price2 > price1) {

            return -1;
        }
        else {

            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```